# How to accept overflow AND have a default height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap, I have a div with the following css:

```
#notecard.hero-unit
{
    background-image: url("../img/notecard.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    height: 1%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Inside of that div I have a varying amount of text `h2` with the following CSS:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

In `#notecard.hero-unit` I am using `overflow: hidden;` and `height: 1%` because most times the text from `h2` scrolls further than `#notecard` - so that job is being handled and `#notecard` now expands to the text inside of `h2`.

However, when `h2` only has a line or two, `#notecard` is very small. I would like `#notecard` to be a default size - let's say `300px` and still accept the overflow if there is any.

I've tried setting height at `#noteard` and also height at `h2` to `300px`, but both ignore the overflow that I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired, but I'm not sure what the goal is. Why not put a min-height on #notecard and call it a day? http://jsfiddle.net/M9bX8

Comment: I'd love to blame being too tired, and the wine, but unfortunately I'm just terrible at design. Min-height is what I needed. Want to submit an answer and I'll accept? Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. We've all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a min-height on the parent of the H2:

```
<style>
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
.hero-unit {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="hero-unit">
   <h2>Some Text</h2>
</div>
<br>

<div class="hero-unit">
   <h2>Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. Much more text. </h2>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M9bX8/5/